# Unexpected implicit resolution in scala

Tags: scala, types, implicit, type-level-computation

I was trying to work out some simple examples of type-level programming in Scala 2.11. Here is a function to tell type equality:

```
def type_==[A, B](implicit ev: A =:= B = null) = ev != null
```

Here `=:=` is defined in the prelude, but for our purpose, even a simple definition such as

```
class =:=[A, B]
implicit def equalTypeInstance[A] = new =:=[A, A]
```

would do. To be sure, can do

```
type_==[Int, String] // false
type_==[Int, Int] // true
```

Next, I encode booleans as types - to make things simple, I avoid to define any operation

```
sealed trait Bool
trait True extends Bool
trait False extends Bool
```

I can again check that

```
type_==[True, True] // true
```

So I thought I might convert `Bool` to `Boolean` by doing

```
def bool2boolean[A <: Bool] = type_==[A, True]
```

Here's the catch:

```
bool2boolean[True] // false
```

Can anyone explain the reason why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicits don't magically pass through functions - each function creates its own scope, and the implicit resolution happens there:

```
def bool2boolean[A <: Bool] = type_==[A, True]
```

*In this scope* the compiler attempts to resolve a `=:=[A, True]`, can't find one, and so this function always returns `False`.

Try passing the evidence through this function:

```
def bool2boolean[A <: Bool](implicit ev: A =:= True = null) =
  type_==[A, True]
```